# Как правильно фильтровать данные

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка, фильтр работает только для первого ряда объекта. Или может я вовсе не так фильтрую данные, подскажите пожалуйста как правильнее будет.

```
var list_products = [
    {
        type: "Домашний",
        OC: "Linux",
        processor: "intel core i5",
        RAM: "6гб",
        hardDrive: "1тб",
        videoCard: "NVIDIA"
    },
    {
        type: "Игровой",
        OC: "Windows",
        processor: "intel core i7",
        RAM: "8гб",
        hardDrive: "2тб",
        videoCard: "AMD"
    },
    {
        type: "Офисный",
        OC: "Mac OS",
        processor: "intel core i5",
        RAM: "4гб",
        hardDrive: "500гб",
        videoCard: "Интегрированая"
    }
];

function production () {
    var key;
    document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = '';
    for (key in list_products) {
        document.getElementById('data').innerHTML += 
        'Тип: ' + list_products[key].type + ('\n') + '<br>' 
        + 'ОС: ' +  list_products[key].OC + ('\n') + '<br>'
        + 'Процессор: ' +  list_products[key].processor + ('\n') + '<br>'
        + 'Оперативная память: ' +  list_products[key].RAM + ('\n') + '<br>'
        + 'Жесткий диск: ' +  list_products[key].hardDrive + ('\n') + '<br>'
        + 'Видео карта: ' +  list_products[key].videoCard  + ('\n') + '<br>' + '</br>' + '<hr>';
    }
}

function productFilter () {
    var key, val;
    var paramPC = [], a = [];
    a = document.getElementsByName('c');
    document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = '';

    for (var i=0; i<=a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].type == "checkbox" && a[i].checked && a[i].name === "c") {
            // console.log("selected: " + a[i].value);
            val = a[i].value;
            paramPC.push(val);
            console.log(paramPC);

            for (key in list_products) {

                if (paramPC[i] == list_products[key].type || 
                    paramPC[i] == list_products[key].OC ||
                    paramPC[i] == list_products[key].processor ||
                    paramPC[i] == list_products[key].RAM ||
                    paramPC[i] == list_products[key].hardDrive ||
                    paramPC[i] == list_products[key].videoCard) {
                    list_products.filter(function(list_products) {
                        return list_products[key];
                    });
                    console.log(list_products[key]);

                        console.log(list_products[key].type);
                        document.getElementById('data').innerHTML += 
                        'Тип: ' + list_products[key].type + ('\n') + '<br>' 
                        + 'ОС: ' +  list_products[key].OC + ('\n') + '<br>'
                        + 'Процессор: ' +  list_products[key].processor + ('\n') + '<br>'
                        + 'Оперативная память: ' +  list_products[key].RAM + ('\n') + '<br>'
                        + 'Жесткий диск: ' +  list_products[key].hardDrive + ('\n') + '<br>'
                        + 'Видео карта: ' +  list_products[key].videoCard  + ('\n') + '<br>' + '</br>' + '<hr>'
                        // + '<a href="index.html">Вернутся на главную</a>'
                        ;


                } else {
                    console.log("net");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

production();

<div class="options">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        Тип<br><br>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="c" value="Домашний"> Домашний</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="c" value="Игровой"> Игровой</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="c" value="Офисный"> Офисный</p>
        <hr><br>
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
        Предустановленая ОС<br><br>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="c" value="Linux"> Linux</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="c" value="Mac OS"> Mac OS</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="c" value="Windows"> Windows</p>
        <hr><br>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
        Процессор<br><br>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="c" value="intel core i3"> intel core i3</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="c" value="intel core i5"> intel core i5</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="c" value="intel core i7"> intel core i7</p>
        <hr><br>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
        Объем оперативной памяти<br><br>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="c" value="4гб"> 4гб</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="c" value="6гб"> 6гб</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="c" value="8гб"> 8гб</p>
        <hr><br>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
        Объем жесткого носителя<br><br>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="c" value="500гб"> 500гб</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="c" value="1тб"> 1тб</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="c" value="2тб"> 2тб</p>
        <hr><br>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
        Видеоарта<br><br>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="c" value="NVIDIA"> NVIDIA</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="c" value="AMD"> AMD</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="c" value="Интегрированая"> Интегрированая</p>
        <hr><br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button onclick="productFilter()">Подобрать</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: уже ведь был такой вопрос с этим кодом.

Comment: Да был(( Но так и не подсказали что не так, а я уже не наю что делать. Где ошибка не могу понять(( Не подскажете пожалуйста?

Comment: для того чтобы сказать _почему_, нужно знать что вообще должен делать этот код, и что он делает на самом деле. Сейчас видно, что идет бесполезный вызов `list_products.filter` - если его убрать, ничего не поменяется, а так же какая-то большая проверка, непонятно что проверяющая

Comment: Код должен выполнять фильтрацию объектов, точнее массива объектов. Есть html форма на которой находится checkbox-ы, у которых имеются значения. При выборе некоторых checkbox данные должны фильтроваться и выводится то что мы ищем. Сейчас добавлю html код для большей наглядности.

Answer (score 1):

Я разобрался вроде бы, и вот что получилось.

```
function production () {
    var key, answer;
    document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = '';
    for (key in list_products) {
        console.table(list_products[key]);
    }
    for (key in list_products) {
        answer = list_products.filter(function(el, ind, arr) {
            return el.type == "Домашний" && el.OC == "Linux";
        });
    }
    console.log(answer);
}
```

Comment: в чем смысл второго `for..in`?

Comment: Да собственно не в чем, можно и одним обойтись.